# Supply JSON to a frontend

Tags: javascript, json, templates, frontend, backend

I was wondering of the best way to supply JSON data to my frontend. What I'd like to ask is maybe there are some better solutions of doing this which I'm missing out. Here are a couple of obvious thoughts of the top of my head:

1) Simply output JSON data in a template as a global JS variable and
   pick it up later on when needed in some JS.

//a template

```
var json = echo json_encode($data);
```

//a JS

```
alert(json.message)
```

I don't really like this idea. For example, if the frontend is
   written completely on JS, I would have to output all the data, even
   if it's not really used by the user (I don't know which pages he
   would like to visit so I load up data for all the pages). It could
   hit performance and just many redundant JSON.

2) Create some JS data provider which requests necessary pices of
   data from the server when the user really needs it. The provider also
   caches the data it requests so it can instanly return the data
   without requesting aything when the user goes back to some page after
   visiting it.

What do you guys think? Could you recommend some better solution for
   the problem or point out some improvements of the ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this question doesn't fit the boundaries of SO. This kind of question will only produce opinions.

Comment: I'm glad to consider other people's opinions on that matter, can't I do it here on SO?. Basically I want to know how people deal with this kind of problem.

Comment: I agree, but questions about preferred approaches are bordering on off-topic. "**Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.**" - maybe edit your question to try and encourage answers that are more specific?